# How to use SPARQLSelect filter (SPARQLEvaluation["CONTAINS"]) on two named graphs?

Tags: databases, sql

I would like to match triplets from two graphs in a [`RDFStore`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/GraphStore/ref/RDFStore.html)s on the string value of one containing the string value of the other.  To test this I made the following store with named graphs by using some code from the documentation.

```
Needs["GraphStore`"]

foaf[s_] := IRI["http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" <> s];

store =
 RDFStore[{},
  <|foaf["people"] -> {
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["a"], foaf["firstName"], "Till"],
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["a"], foaf["surname"], "Schneider"],
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["b"], foaf["firstName"], "Eva"],
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["b"], foaf["surname"], "Baumgärtner"]
     },
   foaf["streets"] -> {
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["s"], foaf["name"], "Wide Street"],
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["s"], foaf["city"], "Narrows Village"],
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["t"], foaf["name"], "Tillers Ave"],
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["t"], foaf["city"], "Fisher Town"]
     }
   |>]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Using [`SPARQLSelect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/GraphStore/ref/SPARQLSelect.html) and [`SPARQLEvaluation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/GraphStore/ref/SPARQLEvaluation.html) I can query each from each graph individually.

```
SPARQLSelect[
  {
     SPARQLGraph[
      foaf["people"],
      RDFTriple[SPARQLVariable["person"], foaf["firstName"], 
       SPARQLVariable["personFirstName"]]
      ]
     } /; SPARQLEvaluation["CONTAINS"][
     SPARQLVariable["personFirstName"],
     "Til"
     ] -> {"person"}
  ][store]
```

> ```
> {<|"person" -> RDFBlankNode["a"]|>}
> ```

and

```
SPARQLSelect[
  {
     SPARQLGraph[
      foaf["streets"],
      RDFTriple[SPARQLVariable["street"], foaf["name"], 
       SPARQLVariable["streetName"]]
      ]
     } /; SPARQLEvaluation["CONTAINS"][
     SPARQLVariable["streetName"],
     "Til"
     ] -> {"street"}
  ][store]
```

> ```
> {<|"street" -> RDFBlankNode["t"]|>}
> ```

However I do not get any result back when I try to query both graphs together using a filter on variables from each. I am expecting to get the `"a"` item in `foaf["people"]` and the `"t"` item in `foaf["streets"]`.

```
SPARQLSelect[
  {
     SPARQLGraph[
      foaf["people"],
      RDFTriple[SPARQLVariable["person"], foaf["firstName"], 
       SPARQLVariable["personFirstName"]]
      ],
     SPARQLGraph[
      foaf["streets"],
      RDFTriple[SPARQLVariable["street"], foaf["name"], 
       SPARQLVariable["streetName"]]
      ]
     } /; SPARQLEvaluation["CONTAINS"][
       SPARQLVariable["personFirstName"],
       SPARQLVariable["streetName"]
     ] -> {"person", "street"}
  ][store]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

The larger problem is along the lines of using SPARQL to query the `"City"` and "`Airport`" entities to find all airports that contain a city name, calculate the distance between the city and the airport, and select the `"City"` and "`Airport`" with the top 10 differences. The above is the first step to get there.

Comment: In your updated question, your query does not work because you have the order of arguments in the `CONTAINS` the wrong way around. Do `SPARQLEvaluation["CONTAINS"][SPARQLVariable["streetName"], 
 SPARQLVariable["personFirstName"]]` like in my answer instead :)

Comment: @CarlLange Eureka!!!!

Comment: Congratulations on being the first to open a question about SPARQL by the way 

Comment: @CarlLange Thanks?  Another one is coming soon. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use named graphs, you can do the following:

```
data = RDFStore[{}, <|
   foaf["streets"] -> {RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["s"], foaf["name"], 
      "Wide Street"], 
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["s"], foaf["city"], "Narrows Village"], 
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["t"], foaf["name"], "Tillers Ave"], 
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["t"], foaf["city"], "Fisher Town"]},
   foaf["people"] -> {
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["a"], foaf["firstName"], "Till"], 
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["a"], foaf["surname"], "Schneider"], 
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["b"], foaf["firstName"], "Eva"], 
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["b"], foaf["surname"], "Baumgärtner"]
     }
   |>]

SPARQLSelect[{
     SPARQLGraph[foaf@"people",
      RDFTriple[SPARQLVariable["person"], foaf["firstName"], 
       SPARQLVariable["personFirstName"]]],
     SPARQLGraph[foaf@"streets",
      RDFTriple[SPARQLVariable["street"], foaf["name"], 
       SPARQLVariable["streetName"]]]} /; 
    SPARQLEvaluation["CONTAINS"][SPARQLVariable["streetName"], 
     SPARQLVariable["personFirstName"]] -> {"person", "street"}][data]
```

which returns `{<|"person" -> RDFBlankNode["a"], "street" -> RDFBlankNode["t"]|>}`.

This query is equivalent to:

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?person ?street WHERE {
  GRAPH foaf:people {
    ?person foaf:firstName ?personFirstName .
  }
  GRAPH foaf:streets {
    ?street foaf:name ?streetName .
  }
  FILTER (CONTAINS(?streetName, ?personFirstName))
}
```

---

Otherwise, it's not clear to me that you can easily join or query across multiple `RDFStore`s like that. Your query does work if you create a single `RDFStore` with all the triples:

```
data = RDFStore[
  {
   RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["a"], foaf["firstName"], "Till"], 
   RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["a"], foaf["surname"], "Schneider"], 
   RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["b"], foaf["firstName"], "Eva"], 
   RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["b"], foaf["surname"], "Baumgärtner"],
   RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["s"], foaf["name"], "Wide Street"], 
   RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["s"], foaf["city"], "Narrows Village"], 
   RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["t"], foaf["name"], "Tillers Ave"], 
   RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["t"], foaf["city"], "Fisher Town"]
   }
  ]

SPARQLSelect[{RDFTriple[SPARQLVariable["person"], foaf["firstName"], 
      SPARQLVariable["personFirstName"]], 
     RDFTriple[SPARQLVariable["street"], foaf["name"], 
      SPARQLVariable["streetName"]]} /; 
    SPARQLEvaluation["CONTAINS"][SPARQLVariable["streetName"], 
     SPARQLVariable["personFirstName"]] -> {"person", "street"}][data]
```

You can also express this join programatically:

```
SPARQLSelect[{RDFTriple[SPARQLVariable["person"], foaf["firstName"], 
      SPARQLVariable["personFirstName"]], 
     RDFTriple[SPARQLVariable["street"], foaf["name"], 
      SPARQLVariable["streetName"]]} /; 
    SPARQLEvaluation["CONTAINS"][SPARQLVariable["streetName"], 
     SPARQLVariable["personFirstName"]] -> {"person", "street"}][
 RDFStore[Join @@ {First@personData, First@streetData}]]
```

(eg, `RDFStore[Join @@ {First@personData, First@streetData}]`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but you are making the join in the Notebook.  The graph stores are too big to bring them down into the notebook to perform a join. The join as to be in SPARQL on the server.

Comment: I see - that wasn't clear in your question. I don't know that the built-in SPARQL functionality can actually use out-of-core data in this way. Can you point to an example in the documentation?

Comment: Or in fact an example of how you would do this normally, ignoring Wolfram Language (please add it to your question).

Comment: I think I have figured out part of it; the named store with `streetData = RDFStore[{},
  <|foaf["streets"] -> {
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["s"], foaf["name"], "Wide Street"],
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["s"], foaf["city"], "Narrows Village"],
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["t"], foaf["name"], "Tillers Ave"],
     RDFTriple[RDFBlankNode["t"], foaf["city"], "Fisher Town"]
     }
   |>]`

Comment: However, the `SPARQLSelect` in the OP is still not working.

Comment: I don't know SPARQL outside of the Wolfram Language. I am experimenting with it using the Wolfram functions.

Comment: @Edmund See my edit - hope that helps.

Comment: You may be interested in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969377/using-the-graph-keyword-in-sparql-to-fetch-remote-graphs#4970001